# URL works fine as IMG SRC, but not as a DIV's background-image

Tags: css

Why won't the HTML and CSS below show the `DIV` with a `background-image`?  The same URL works fine as the `SRC` of an `IMG` element. https://jsfiddle.net/52ft1erg/1/

```
<style>
img, div { height: 100px; width: 100px}
div { background-image: url (https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia_wordmark@2x.png) }
</style>

<div>This is a DIV</div>

This is an IMG: <img src="https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia_wordmark@2x.png" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the space after "`url`". Arrrgh. `url (https://...` won't work but `url(https://...` will.

I wasted 20 minutes on this before realizing my (dumb) mistake.

I looked around SO for a while to see if this was a duplicate, and although there are several other reasons that `background-image` will fail while `IMG SRC` will succeed (e.g. spaces in the filename, lack of height/width on the element, browser differences, etc.) I couldn't find this particular root cause. So sharing as a Q&A on StackOverflow to prevent others from wasting their time too.